# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I have such a part of code and want to receive link on element that I find in "statistic_info_link".
But it gives me error and write :

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'

Here is structure of html page with JS elements http://www.ukrstat.gov.ua/head.html
As a result I need to find link where is written "Statistic information"-"Статистична інформація"

```
r = requests.get("http://www.ukrstat.gov.ua/") 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text) 
head=soup.find('frame',{'name': 'banner'})
#Recieve link on head
link_head='http://www.ukrstat.gov.ua/'+head.get('src')
browser.get(link_head)
statistic_info_link = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Статистична інформація')]").get_attribute("outerHTML")
print(statistic_info_link)
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are giving `browser.find_elements` it's returning the element in a **List**. And you can use `.get_attribute` to a WebElement not to list of Webelements.

Either change `statistic_info_link = browser.find_elements`  to

```
statistic_info_link = browser.find_element...
```

Or iterate over the list

```
statistic_info_link = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Статистична інформація')]")
for ele in statistic_info_link:
    print(ele.get_attribute("outerHTML"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'
```

The error explains that you are trying to invoke `get_attribute` on a list in Python, but it should have been a web element.

Remember `find_elements` (plural) returns a list in **Python-Selenium bindings**. Where as `find_element` returns a web element in **Python-Selenium bindings**

**Problem solution :**

1. In most cases changing to find_element should fix the issue.

So, Instead of

```
statistic_info_link = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Статистична інформація')]").get_attribute("outerHTML")
print(statistic_info_link)
```

do this :

```
statistic_info_link = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Статистична інформація')]").get_attribute("innerHTML")
print(statistic_info_link)
```

Also, I am not really sure about `outerHTML`, hence I have changed that to `innerHTML`.

**Second Fix :**

Use the list index :

```
statistic_info_link = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Статистична інформація')]")[0].get_attribute("outerHTML")
print(statistic_info_link)
```

or

```
statistic_info_link = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Статистична інформація')]")[0].get_attribute("innerHTML")
print(statistic_info_link)
```

lastly if you really want to extract text from a list please use below code :

```
statistic_info_link = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Статистична інформація')]").get_attribute("outerHTML")
for ele in statistic_info_link :
    print(ele.get_attribute("outerHTML"))
```

or

```
statistic_info_link = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Статистична інформація')]").get_attribute("outerHTML")
for ele in statistic_info_link :
    print(ele.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```